# Android - Is posible save entire Bundle into SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, save, bundle, sharedpreferences, parcelable

I would like to save a Bundle object (parcelable) into SharedPreferences... is this possible?

There is any other option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) it looks like there is no method to save a parcelable object inside shared preferences. Depending on the size of the object you want to save you could choose between serializing it in a string and saving in shared preferences as a string or save it to a file.

Comment: Thank you!, I resolved my problem using other kind of Storage:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal